# How to avoid "/Home" in the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using the standard MVC template in VS 2013.

With the default set up, http://website/ will be routed to website/Home/Index.

How do I route all "actions" directly under website root url, eg http://website/xxx, to show the same content as http://website/Home/xxx?  For example, how do I make http://website/About to execute the About action in the Home controller?  If possible, the solution shouldn't be a Http redirect to http://website/Home/About because I don't want to show the "ugly" Home/ in the url.

Comment: I've removed the 'basic q' part, it's rather obvious that this is a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try out like the following one

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyAppHome",
                url: "{action}/{wa}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", wa = UrlParameter.Optional, area = "Admin" },
                namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers" }
            ).DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Admin" });
```

Here, you may notice that the Home controller is hardcoded and is no longer to be supplied in the request. you can also make use of the `RouteDebugger` to play with routes.

HTH

Comment: Looks like there is an error in your code.  I changed url to "{action}/{wa}" and it gives what I want, ie website/About will output content of website/Home/About.  I have always wondered how it knows that in url:{A}/{B}/{C} what A is and what B is.  In url:"{action}/{wa}" why doesn't it think that `action` is the controller?

Comment: It was posted by oversight. It is because we have a default value for the controller and the URL is in the pattern that accepts only action and paramters

Comment: Thanks. My last question was: given the url website/X, how does it know that X should be a controller or an action?  Eg, website/About should it be mapped to /Home/About or should it be mapped to /About/Index?

Comment: I have hit an unwanted side effect. By adding the above code before the default routes.MapRoute in the built-in file, I lost all other /Controller/Action urls.  For example /Account/Login now gives a 404.  Does it mean that I have to add a route for every controller I have?

Comment: Did you have a route for controller/action. Else, you can switch to attribute routing, which you can control easily

Comment: Thanks. I have rephrased the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386170/how-to-make-one-controller-the-default-one-when-only-action-specified and learned much about routing. There is no magic to it. It's just simple pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find an answer to this that covered all issues one would face with a public facing website without being a pain to upkeep while still maintaining flexibility.

I ended up coming up with the following. It allows for use of multiple controllers, doesn't require any upkeep, and makes all URLs lowercase.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //set up constraints automatically using reflection - shouldn't be an issue as it only runs on appstart
        var homeConstraints = @"^(?:" + string.Join("|", (typeof(Controllers.HomeController)).GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Select(x => (x.Name == "Index" ? "" : x.Name))) + @")$";

        //makes all urls lowercase, which is preferable for a public facing website
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //maps routes with a single action to only those methods specified within the home controller thanks to contraints
        routes.MapRoute(
            "HomeController",
            "{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { action = homeConstraints }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```